# Eigenvalues over Commutative Rings

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to ask if there are existing theories and/or references to solve for eigenvalues of matrices over commutative rings. I am specifically working on matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_n$.